# Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State in Ocelot

Tags: signalr, .net-5, ocelot

I am using Ocelot for API gateway with SignalR for real-time data update functionality in Asp.Net Core.

I have created three projects: APIGateway, AspNetCoreAPISignalR, AspNet core Web APP (as a client app)

- I have created Message Hub in AspNetCoreAPISignalR project to broadcast messages to clients
- Without using an API gateway, I am able to broadcast the messages to all the clients in real-time.
- But as I have to use Ocelot as API gateway, I am getting below error - "Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State."

---

API Gateway configuration file:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [    
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{catchAll}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 35685
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{catchAll}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" ]
    }    
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:44353"
  }
}
```

---

API Gateway startup file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true)
            .AllowCredentials();
        }));

        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddOcelot();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseOcelot().Wait();
    }
}
```

---

Microservice start up file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true)
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ServerSignalR", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ServerSignalR v1"));
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/messagehub");
        });
    }
-----
```

What can I try next, to get Ocelot and signalR to work together?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.